# Invalid Hook Call. React

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, next.js

[image]I am new to React.js and I bought source code of web application. I have good experience in pure javascript. so I did all thing's and everything is working fine. except one I am getting the error shown in the ​screenshot.

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

const initialState = {
  isOpen: false,
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isOpen: !state.isOpen,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export const DrawerContext = React.createContext({});

export const DrawerProvider = ({ children }) => { <-- Error
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <DrawerContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </DrawerContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: [Your code works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/0x0x0z4p2p). You most likely have two different versions of React installed at the same time.

Comment: i did npm ls react it out only single react version..any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you have the same version of `react` and `react-dom` installed?

Comment: yes both are 16.8.6

Comment: This is only possible if `React` object that `react-dom` uses isn't the same as `React` that is used in a component. This can be caused by package duplication, mismatching versions, accidental usage of global `React` or `ReactDOM` instead of imported one, whatever. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate your problem, otherwise it can be considered off-topic.