# Reactjs Redux. Getting ' Invalid hook call' while using only while using connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my Songs.js

```
class Songs extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 Song List 
            </div>   
        );
    }   
} 
export default connect()(Songs);
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
    return <div>
    <Songs/>
    </div>
};

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <App /> 
</Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root"))
```

I'm trying to learn React Redux.

In the Songs.js file, I get the invalid Hooks error only while using connect. The app works perfectly well when I'm not trying to use redux connect

Comment: I can't reproduce. Could you share import statements, or clarify if you're taking an action that's causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

As an FYI I was able to duplicate and have opened an issue with react-redux.

Issue: 
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1303

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are importing connect from `Redux`.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

I assume if `connect` uses hooks now, that you are using versions of `Redux` that are compatible with hooks (>16.8).

Make sure `React` and `React-Dom` are the same versions.

[Might be related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551950/invalid-hook-call-react)

[The official docs.](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)